# I am trying to initialize admob ads in Fragment of a Android App

Tags: java, android

I am trying to initialize admob ads in Fragment of Android App Is this the right way to do it

`@Override public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState); MobileAds.initialize(getActivity()); }`

and do we need to initialize in every Fragment or whether one is enough?

Tried in one fragement

Comment: You can initialize in Application class once. No need to re-initialize in every fragment or activity

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to initialize when the App starts (In Splash Screen Activity)

1. You need to initialize the AdMob one time only not in every Activity or Fragment (After this just load and show the Ads)
2. If you want it to initialize in Fragment I'll suggest you use
   requireActivity() instead of getActivity() method

Comment: It is suggested to initialise Ads SDK as early as possible. You could initialise it in `Application` class or via any `Initialiser (Startup library)` if implemented already in the app.